# How to resolve memory leak in IIS Single Page App

Tags: .net, iis, .net-4.5, windbg, iis-8

I have an older .net Framework 4.5.2 Single Page App (SPA) that has been running with no memory issues for about 5 years.

Then about 1 month ago, it started exhibiting a memory leak.  There were no major code changes (minor tweaks are done in the client, but nothing that would cause a memory leak).

The app has about 100 concurrent users.  The typical memory usage is stable at about 1.5 gigs.  When the leak is triggered, the memory usage will rapidly rise over the course of about two minutes to over 2 gigs at which point the AppPool recycles to re-claim the memory.  It takes about 5 minutes for the original app pool to terminate.  During that time, the memory usage will reach about 8 gigs before terminating.

The end users are not affected by this.

The new AppPool worker will then follow the same pattern of rising up to 8 gigs in a couple of minutes.  This will continue for about 15 minutes at which point the issue disappears for the rest of the day.  But the next day, it will be back.

There is no obvious explanation for why this is occurring.  Testing cannot reproduce the issue.

The app is an order entry app which access a SQL Server database on another server.  There were some Stored Procedure changes made, but if one of those were the cause of the issue, it seems to me that the memory issue would happen on the Sql Server host machine, not IIS.

What I have done to try to debug:

1. I have looked through the IIS logs at the time it is triggered.  No unusual activity is seen.
2. I captured a memory dump, and I tried to view the memory using [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) But I was unable to get any data out of it.
3. I have checked the event log of the IIS Host and there are no exceptions or warnings being generated.
4. SQL Server is checked for any issues, but none found with no unusual activity.
5. Tried moving the App to a different IIS Server, but the problem was the same there.

Any advice on how to track down this problem would be appreciated.

The only thing I have not tried yet is updating the libraries.  There have been many updates since the app was written, but I am hesitant to update without a clear reason, having been bitten by this in the past.

There has to be something which is eating up so much memory so quickly.

Comment: When you said "...using WinDbg But I was unable to get any data out of it", were you following the guides like Tess's? https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/ Besides, memory leak might also happen on the unmanaged side, which DebugDiag's leak tracing rule can help analyze.

Comment: Have you confirmed that Windows updates, .NET Framework updates or some other software/dependency updates are not the cause?

Comment: Also, `(minor tweaks are done in the client, but nothing that would cause a memory leak)` - you're 100% sure that is the case? Have you tried reverting those changes to double check?

Comment: @LexLi, That link looks very interesting.  I am going to spend some time going through the articles and get up to speed on WinDbg and that should point to the problem.

Comment: It is difficult to troubleshoot your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.